Is it possible to use OxyPlot with Uno Platform?
I am trying to transfer a UWP project to Uno Platform. I want to run the app on Linux later and I am using VS22. The project uses OxyPlot to plot some charts and I am having problems to integrate OxyPlot in my Uno project.
Adding the NuGet packages is fine and also adding the using directive to the view model works fine. but as soon as I am adding OxyPlot to the xaml view I get an error when compiling the project.
xmlns:oxy="using:OxyPlot"
Error  WMC1006 Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Uno.UI, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.'
I am not sure which Nuget package I should use. I tried different packages, but all with the same result. I think H.OxyPlot.Uno.WinUI is correct, but I am not sure.
Has anyone ever used OxyPlot for what I am trying to do and how can this be solved?

For the moment, H.OxyPlot does not support Uno v5.
I just created an issue on the H.OxyPlot repo.
https://github.com/HavenDV/H.OxyPlot/issues/18
UPDATE
It seems that H.OxyPlot will support Uno v5.
https://github.com/HavenDV/H.OxyPlot/issues/18#issuecomment-2160752358
